# Multi-Value parameter In MS SSRS with Sybase backend?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sybase

Is there anyway to have a multi-value parameter with a SYBASE backend. It seems that there is an issue with compatibility between the two.  I get a

> > Cannot add multi value query parameter for dataset becuase it is not supported by data extension.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: I think you have to use an adapter: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35890.1550/doc/html/jon1256941734395.html  Because SSRS uses OLE DB or ODBC

Comment: I think you're right.  Was just hoping for a work around, I've tried reformating the parameter output and setting the available values at one time and that seemed to kind of have worked but since it wasn't being pulled from a Query it wasn't going to update automatically. I don't know how I did it though.